# My bluetooth is disabled in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: bluetooth

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.10 and found both wifi and bluetooth is not working.
I could able to regain my wifi and bluetooth is still disabled. Please need some help. I have seen a lot of posts and found nothing which can resolve my issue.

hcitool dev -- output
Devices:

Comment: Edit your question to include `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `lsusb` and `rfkill list all`  What make and model is this PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device needs firmware to work

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/bor5hy8djhztpsf/fw-04ca_200b.hcd
sudo cp fw-04ca_200b.hcd /lib/firmware
sudo cp fw-04ca_200b.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm
```

Reboot and try

Edit: `wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnlvxmw5l7mwn2d/bluetooth.tar.gz`

`tar -zxvf bluetooth.tar.gz`

It should create a folder named bluetooth to your home folder, then `cd bluetooth`
And then we need to get some files downloaded `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential`

Now we copy files from your current config

`cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers`

`cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config`

Now we can make the modules with

`make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules`

Now we unload the current module

`sudo modprobe -r btusb` and copy in the new one with

`sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/`

And it is time to test and insert the module `sudo modprobe btusb` and with any luck your bluetooth works fine, if not a reboot should work.

If you update and find bluetooth doesn't work after a reboot then `cd bluetooth`

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Still not working.. Bluetooth is still showing as disabled.

Comment: can you show the results of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` and `dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: Please find my output in the answer... Thank you

Comment: Please show results from `hciconfig -a`

Comment: NOthing is showing up in hciconfig -a

Comment: Results from `uname -a`  I will see if I can dig up a different firmware file also

Comment: Linux deepika-IdeaPad-U430-Touch 3.16.0-31-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 10 15:24:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The code might need to be changed in btusb for yours to work and I can do that but show me `modinfo btusb | grep alias | grep -i 04ca`

Comment: `modinfo btusb | grep alias | grep -i 04ca`
`alias:          usb:v04CAp2003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: That is the cause, I can make you a patched kernel module to fix it later after work

Comment: I found I don't have 3.16.0-31 on any machine anymore.  This might be better so you don't have the same question when a new kernel downloads as modules like this are kernel specific and sooner or later you should find this is not needed after a kernel update because the kernel will have the patch I applied to btusb.c in the bluetooth folder

Answer (score 0):

iam using lenovo u430. Below are the output each command.

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:062e]
    Kernel driver in use: wl`

`lsusb`

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04ca:200b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0538 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0060 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 0):

`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    9.247823] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    9.247843] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.247851] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.247853] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.247864] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.251480] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.251483] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.251490] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.251945] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.251953] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.251958] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11`

dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.180970] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored