# Bluetooth is not working on ubuntu 14.04 on lenovo G50

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo, realtek

My bluetooth is not not working on ubuntu 14.04. I am not sure whether my bluetooth adapter is not getting recognized or necessary drivers are absent. I tried many things but no luck. I found that similar issue was resolved on question.
[[My bluetooth is disabled in Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594347/my-bluetooth-is-disabled-in-ubuntu-14-10][1])

Following is the output of necessary commands.

```
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3821]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0621]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ 


dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:579a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ 


dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ 



dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   18.546763] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   18.546779] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.546784] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.546787] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.546795] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.549488] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   18.549496] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   18.549500] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   18.701848] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.701851] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.701854] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ 



dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ uname -a
Linux dexter-Lenovo-G50-80 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ hciconfig -a
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ 

dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ modinfo btusb | grep alias | grep -i 04ca
alias:          usb:v04CAp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp2003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$
```

I also tried following steps mentioned in tagged question but was getting following error:

```
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnlvxmw5l7mwn2d/bluetooth.tar.gz
--2015-08-19 14:37:45--  https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnlvxmw5l7mwn2d/bluetooth.tar.gz
Resolving www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)... 108.160.172.238, 108.160.172.206
Connecting to www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)|108.160.172.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘bluetooth.tar.gz’

    [       <=>                                                                                                                                                          ] 85,039      46.0KB/s   in 1.8s   

2015-08-19 14:37:48 (46.0 KB/s) - ‘bluetooth.tar.gz’ saved [85039]

dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ tar -zxvf bluetooth.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$
```

Please note I have dual boot and bluetooth is working fine in windows.

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open terminal and enter `sudo update usb-ids` then run `lsusb` once again and edit the post

Comment: @Jeremy31 No need. There is the id.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I am all wrong. It is Broadcom. `105b:e065`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: @Jeremy31 Getting following output after the command.               dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo update usb-ids
[sudo] password for dexter: 
sudo: update: command not found

Comment: It must be `sudo update-usbids` and check `modinfo btusb | grep -i 105b`

Comment: File a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug) as your bluetooth isn't supported under the 3.19 kernel but it should work in 3.13.0-59 from Ubuntu

Comment: @Pilot6: I followed the steps you had given in ques [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04) but still no luck.. :(
Please help me out

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have installed kernel 3.13.0-59 as well. Now bluetooth is getting detected but its not able to find any bluetooth devices. Also, my wifi is not working now. Moreover when i followed the steps in [linke] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) , kernel 3.19 kernel is getting updated and not 3.13.  It seems even though i m in kernel 3.13, system is pointing to 3.19. How can i change that. Thanks in advance

Comment: For 3.13 kernel `wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/f503f6r686riiow/fw-105b_e065.hcd` and `sudo cp fw-105b_e065.hcd /lib/firmware/`     `sudo modprobe -r btusb`    `sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: @Pilot6 [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1486898)